# Numpy selection of the same idx on both raw and columns

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Today I encounter a strange selection:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], 
              [4, 5, 6], 
              [7, 8, 9]])

idx = [0, 1]

A[idx, idx]
A[idx, :][:, idx]
```

I don't understand the output of the first selection `A[idx, idx]`: `array([1, 5])`.

Comment: `A[[0, 1], [0, 1]]` -> `A[0, 0], A[1, 1]`

Comment: `A[np.ix_(idx, idx)]` selects the block.  Indexing arrays `broadcast` against each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [85]: A = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
In [86]: idx=[0,1]
```

This selects a 'diagonal', the values of the 2 lists are paired:

```
In [87]: A[idx,idx]
Out[87]: array([1, 5])
```

If you want block, use `ix_`:

```
In [88]: A[np.ix_(idx,idx)]
Out[88]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])
```

`ix_` transforms the inputs into a tuple that broadcasts against each other in a multidimensional way:

```
In [89]: np.ix_(idx,idx)
Out[89]: 
(array([[0],
        [1]]),
 array([[0, 1]]))
```

`ogrid` produces the same thing from slices:

```
In [90]: np.ogrid[:2,:2]
Out[90]: 
[array([[0],
        [1]]),
 array([[0, 1]])]
```

while `mgrid` creates the same, but fully expanded into a 3d array. That may help visualize how the `ix_` tuple broadcasts to select the block:

```
In [91]: np.mgrid[:2,:2]
Out[91]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])
```

In MATLAB `(idx,idx)` selects the block, but selecting the diagonal requires translating the 2d indices into a 1d, with `subs2ind`.  `numpy` block indexing is a bit more complex, but more general.

Comment: Thank you very much. With this answer, I finally learn something new! `np.ix_` looks like the correct way to go for my use case, the selection of channels on a noise covariance matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Because `A[[0,1],:]` back to you `row zero and one` then with `A[[0,1],[0,1]]` in `row zero` you got `column zero` and in `row one` you got `column one`.

```
A[[0,1], :]
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 6]])

A[[0,1],[0,1]]
# array([1, 5])
```

Comment: What would be the correct syntax then to do the second selection `A[idx, :][:, idx]`. It feels wrong to do this selection in 2 steps.

Comment: @Mathieu I don't do in two-step, for explaining I send example

Comment: @Mathieu for `A[[0,1], :]` you get all columns for `row zero and one` and for `A[:,[0,1]]` you get all rows in `column zero and one`, am I wrong?

Comment: `A[[0,1], :]` selects rows 0 and 1; A[:,[0,1]] selects columns 0 and 1.

Comment: @Mathieu exactly

Comment: Ok; but this syntax of chaining selections `A[[0, 1], :][:, [0, 1]]` for something as simple as this seems dumb. What would be a better syntax to achieve this selection?

Comment: @Mathieu better syntax for which selection? for this : A[[0,1],[0,1]]?

Comment: you could use `A[:2,:2]`? or `A[:2][:,:2]` if you insist on chaining

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this:

```
A[[0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

Which is basically:

```
[A[0, 0], A[1, 1]]
```

Which of course is [1, 5] in your example data.

NumPy calls this "integer advanced indexing."

Comment: Ok.. I've been using a fair bit of numpy and never notice this. In my mind `A[[0, 1], [0, 1]]` means: select index 0 and 1 on the first dimension; selection index 0 and 1 on the second dimension. Is there a better syntax for the second selection `A[idx, :][:, idx]`, it feels wrong to do it in 2 steps.

Comment: @Mathieu: You can use `A[0:2,0:2]` for that.

Comment: Sadly I can not; this is a dummy example. Consider the case where instead of `idx = [0,1]` I want to get rid of the column and row `1`, i.e. `idx=[0, 2]`. In practice, this is a sub-selection of channels on a noise covariance matrix.